# Como hacer referencia a la carpeta resources de un proyecto java para guardar un archivo?

Tags: java, rutas

estoy comenzando a programar y estoy intentando hacer una aplicación de escritorio que permita cargar una imagen de un JFileChooser para después guardar una copia en la carpeta resources (src\main\resources\nombre.jpg).

El problema que tengo es que no se como hacer referencia a la carpeta de salida (resources). Lo que intento hacer es:

```
private static void copiarFile(String entradaPath, String nombre){
    File entrada = new File(entradaPath);
    File salida = new File("\\resources\\"+nombre+".jpeg");
    
    try {
        Files.copy(entrada.toPath(), salida.toPath());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
```

donde `entradaPath` es el path que obtengo de un JFileChooser
Como dije el problema debe ser que no estoy usando bien el `File salida = new File("\\resources\\"+nombre+".jpeg");`

Gracias!!!

Comment: Como te comenta  @E. Betanzos, si se puede pero ese directorio no es para eso. Principalmente porque ese directorio solo existe cuando trabajas con el IDE, cuando se entrega un producto se entrega solo un jar o un war. Es decir que en ejecuciones finales lo normal es que ya no levantes tu aplicación con el IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pides es imposible de hacer una vez que tengas tu aplicación en producción, por dos motivos:

1. La carpeta `resources` forma parte de la estructura de un proyecto Maven pero solo sirve para organizar los archivos de tu aplicación y no formará parte del artefacto que será generado (el archivo JAR resultante). Esto pasa también con la carpeta `java` (`src/main/java`), donde metes los archivos *.java* pero esta carpeta no formará parte de la estructura de paquetes del JAR del proyecto.
2. El contenido de la carpeta `resources` será copiado en la raíz del archivo JAR del proyecto, al igual que el contenido de la carpeta `java`.

Esto implica que para leer dichos archivos (los que están dentro de la carpeta `resources` del proyecto) debes hacerlo tratándolos como recursos de la aplicación usando los métodos: [Class#getResource(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) y [Class#getResourceAsStream(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-). Por otra parte, tampoco podrás guardar nada en la carpeta `resources`, que sería la raíz del archivo JAR, porque dentro del JAR no puedes escribir nada.

Te recomiendo que estos archivos los guardes en una carpeta que hayas creados al mismo nivel de tu proyecto y por ende al mismo nivel que tu JAR en producción.

[image: Carpetas del proyecto]
[image: Carpetas de la aplicación en producción]

PD: Sí se pude "escribir dentro de un JAR", pero para hacerlo hay que extraer todo su contenido y luego reempaquetarlo (muy similiar a como se hace con archivos ZIP, RAR, etc. ya que estos son muy similares a los ZIPs).

Comment: Entiendo, agradezco mucho tu respuesta y si voy a hacer eso de colocarlos en una carpeta al mismo nivel del proyecto.