# ¿Por qué cuando hago un ejecutable del sistema no se visualizan las imágenes?

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy creando un sistema y me he dado cuenta que cuando lo compilo dentro del IDE de Eclipse me funciona bien, pero cuando creo un ejecutable del mismo las imágenes no se visualizan.

Utilizo este fragmento de código para agregar imágenes:

```
//Imagenes en un JLabel
        JLabel iconoLogin = new JLabel(""); 
        iconoLogin.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        iconoLogin.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/main/Resources/Imagenes/login.png"));

//Imagenes en un JButton
        JButton btnImprimir = new JButton("");
        btnImprimir.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/Imagenes/Printer.png"));
```

**NOTA: Tengo las imágenes, reportes y librerías en otro paquete llamado Resources, por eso le especifico la ruta de donde está ubicada la imagen. El paquete princpal es el que se llama Java donde se ubican los archivos .JAVA**

¿Qué me recomiendan hacer?

Gracias.

Comment: Una vez dentro del jar, las cosas funcionan diferente... prueba a obtener las imágenes como recursos, ya que las tienes en resources: `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Printer.png"))`.

Comment: Lo voy a probar, gracias!

Comment: Tienes que usar la forma que te comenta @Benito-B porque el directorio de `src/main/resources` en un directorio que solo existe en el entorno de desarrollo y no se exporta al JAR. No obstante has la prueba con la ruta "/Imagenes/Printer.png".

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como hacer referencia a la carpeta resources de un proyecto java para guardar un archivo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/441629/como-hacer-referencia-a-la-carpeta-resources-de-un-proyecto-java-para-guardar-un)